# Pinging an array of ip addresses concurrently in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an array of objects with properties "IP" for storing an ip address and "LastAlive" for storing the date that the server last responded to a ping.

In order to fill the LastAlive properties I use the following function:

```
function Update-AliveStatus ($nodes)
{
    foreach ($node in $nodes)
    {
        $alive = Test-Connection $node.IP -Quiet -Count 2
        if ($alive -eq $true)
        {
            $node.LastAlive = (Get-Date)
        }
    }
    return $nodes
}
```

This works fine unless the list of IPs is long, in which case it takes ages to iterate through all of them. How can I modify the function to run the pings asynchronously and still return the filled array when all the pings are done?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rslaten/archive/2013/07/30/pinging-a-list-of-machines-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Or even better: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/20/use-powershell-workflow-to-ping-computers-in-parallel.aspx